# MySQL - How to sum multiple ranges from same column

Tags: mysql

I have been working on this, off and on, for a few days now. I have to read a MySQL table (described below) to determine which groups are in the table. The code column values can go from 01 to 99 and these values are divided into four code groups. I currently get the code groups this way:

```
SELECT SUM(code) AS code0 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 1 AND 69 ;
SELECT SUM(code) AS code1 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 ;
SELECT SUM(code) AS code2 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 ;
SELECT SUM(code) AS code3 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 ;
```

but would really like to be able to do this in one query. I've tried CASE/WHEN/END but I just can't seem to get it right. I have tried many versions, but this one comes closest:

(doesn't work, but close)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE code WHEN code BETWEEN 1 AND 69 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code0,
    SUM(CASE code WHEN code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code1,
    SUM(CASE code WHEN code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code2,
    SUM(CASE code WHEN code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code3
  FROM codes;
```

returns:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| code0 | code1 | code2 | code3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

(This is only counting the '01' entry ???)

But, what works are my four separate queries, which return:

```
SELECT SUM(code) AS code0 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 1 AND 69 ;
+-------+
| code0 |
+-------+
|    55 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT SUM(code) AS code1 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 ;
+-------+
| code1 |
+-------+
|   213 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT SUM(code) AS code2 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 ;
+-------+
| code2 |
+-------+
|   326 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT SUM(code) AS code3 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 ;
+-------+
| code3 |
+-------+
|  NULL |
+-------+
```

THE DATA STUFF --

```
codes table schema:
+-------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code        | smallint(2) unsigned zerofill | NO   |     | 00      |       |
| descrip     | varchar(30)                   | NO   |     |         |       |
+-------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

table data:

```
select * from codes;
+------+---------+
| code | descrip |
+------+---------+
|   01 | RWF     |
|   02 | BLK     |
|   03 | BWF     |
|   04 | CHAR    |
|   05 | RED     |
|   06 | XBRED   |
|   07 | MIXED   |
|   08 | HOLST   |
|   09 | JERSEY  |
|   10 | LGHRN   |
|   70 | WHT     |
|   71 | BLK     |
|   72 | SPOTTED |
|   80 | WHT     |
|   81 | BLK     |
|   82 | BLKFC   |
|   83 | WHTFC   |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: I don't understand how summing these figures produces a useful result!?! If the values were bit integers (2,4,8,16,...) then it would make sense, but otherwise, how is it useful?

Comment: @Strawberry ours is not to reason why... :-)

Comment: Nick I think ours very much is to reason why. That's how you avoid cataclysmic errors like the charge of the light brigade (down the wrong valley) , or the summation of random cattle codes!

Comment: @Strawberry basically I was agreeing violently with you (perhaps a bit too subtly)... bit masks would make a lot more sense for this.

Comment: @Strawberry, I did supply SQL queries, both the ones that work that I am using and the one that doesn't work. I'm not sure what else I should provide.

Comment: @Nick, this is simply used to find out which color groups are represented. The values don't matter other than zero (color group not defined) or not zero (color group defined). I should have specified this in my question, sorry!

Comment: @KevinNathan ok - that makes sense. But in that case using queries based on `COUNT` or `EXISTS` would be more efficient than `SUM`. See the edit to my answer

Comment: @Strawberry it turns out `SUM` does produce a useful result, but just one that can be produced more efficiently.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that this is simply an issue of data display, which to my mind would be better resolved in application code. With regards to my first comment, if I have to explain the link, then it rather defeats the point of providing the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't quite have your [`CASE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) correct, you are mixing the two forms and ending up comparing `code` with a boolean value, which is why it only sums values for `code = 1`. This is the correct form:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN  1 AND 69 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code3
FROM codes;
```

Output:

```
code0   code1   code2   code3
55      213     326     0
```

Based on your comments about the usage of the value, the following queries using `COUNT` or `EXISTS` would be more efficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 1 AND 69 THEN code END) AS code0,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN code END) AS code1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN code END) AS code2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 THEN code END) AS code3
FROM codes

SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 1 AND 69) AS code0,
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 70 AND 79) AS code1,
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 80 AND 89) AS code2,
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 90 AND 99) AS code3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cc2jMUhpNEZWe1V4iozNbr/3)

Comment: Both yours and @Adwaith's work fine (they are the same). Thanks very much! I have a much better understanding of the CASE statement, now!

Comment: I am going to go with the SELECT EXISTS since it is much  clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You have got the syntax for the CASE statement incorrectly even though your approach was good. The corrected version is

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 1 AND 69 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN 90 AND 99 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS code3
  FROM codes;
```

The Rule of thumb is when you have a direct comparison use

```
CASE expression
    WHEN test THEN result
    …
    ELSE otherResult
 END
```

When dealing with ranges use

```
CASE
    WHEN booleanExpression THEN result
    …
    ELSE otherResult
 END
```

Answer (score -1):

it should be working.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(code) AS code0 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 1 AND 69) t1,
  (SELECT SUM(code) AS code1 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 70 AND 79) t2,
  (SELECT SUM(code) AS code2 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 80 AND 89) t3,
  (SELECT SUM(code) AS code3 FROM codes WHERE code BETWEEN 90 AND 99) t4
```

Comment: This one works as well, and is actually quite close to one I had tried! However, I think the other two are a bit clearer. Thanks for another view of it.